# How to extend the ls command by a custom column

Tags: ls, command

I wonder if it is possible to modify the `ls -l` command by a custom column.

For example, I would like this column to contain for each file, say, the first line of `$(CustomCommand FILE)`.

Comment: I think maybe you could use a function called by the bashrc alias of ls itself

Comment: Instead of modifying `ls`, why not introduce a script that runs ls and your custom command?  You could alias ls to run this custom command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very basic proof of concept.  Not particularly robust (filenames with spaces will break it for example) but gets the idea across.

```
$ export CustomCommand=file
$ alias ls=/tmp/test/myls
$ ls
a  b  c  myls
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steve steve   0 Sep 22 19:17 a a: empty
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steve steve   0 Sep 22 19:17 b b: empty
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steve steve   0 Sep 22 19:17 c c: empty
-rwxr-xr-x 1 steve steve 127 Sep 22 19:18 myls myls: POSIX shell script,     ASCII text executable
$ cat /tmp/test/myls
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = "-l" ]
then
 shift
 ls -l $* | awk 'NF>2{ printf "%s ",$0 ; system("$CustomCommand " $NF) }'
else
 ls $*
fi
$
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your approach, what is the problem with spaces in filenames? It should only occur for `ls -l`, but `ls -l *` should work, right?

Comment: I used your solution and extended it, such that I can also define the `CustomCommand` as the first argument, i.e. in your case I would type `myls file *`.

Comment: Suppose I had a file named "Walt White" in that directory....the awk would interpret $NF as "White" and try to run "file White" and fail.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach putting together paste, sed, ls and saving it to bashrc. It has two main parts:

- a "custom_command" here which takes arguments but merely prefixes each argument passed to it, with "YYY" and appends "ZZZ", the OP's actual CustomCommand of course would do something different
- an alias named "ls1" that includes calling custom_command. Named it "ls1" to avoid conflict with "ls" because we still rely on "ls"

So in your ~/.bashrc, add:

```
custom_command ()
{
    for i; do
        echo "YYY${i}ZZZ"
    done
}

alias ls1='paste <( ls -lh | sed 1d ) <( custom_command * )'
```

And then `. ~/.bashrc` to make it effective in current terminal.

If the current directory contains 'dir1' 'file1' 'file2' and 'file 3' (to test a file with spaces), you can run the alias `ls1` and see:

```
$ ls1
drwxr-xr-x 2 meme meme 4.0K Sep 22 14:33 dir1   YYYdir1ZZZ
-rw-r--r-- 1 meme meme    8 Sep 22 13:51 file1  YYYfile1ZZZ
-rw-r--r-- 1 meme meme    8 Sep 22 13:51 file2  YYYfile2ZZZ
-rw-r--r-- 1 meme meme   14 Sep 22 15:45 file 3 YYYfile 3ZZZ
```

### Explanation

```
custom_command ()
{
    for i; do
        echo "YYY${i}ZZZ"
    done
}
```

- The `for i` without specifying anything further, will cause for loop to use the positional parameters
- the curly braces are necessary to distinguish the i variable, otherwise bash will misinterpret $iZZZ as a variable

Example output:

```
$ custom_command a b c
YYYaZZZ
YYYbZZZ
YYYcZZZ
```

When used with `*` bash expansion:

```
$ custom_command *
YYYdir1ZZZ
YYYfile1ZZZ
YYYfile2ZZZ
YYYfile 3ZZZ
```

The "ls -lh" normally will do this:

```
$ ls -lh
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 2 meme meme 4.0K Sep 22 14:33 dir1
-rw-r--r-- 1 meme meme    8 Sep 22 13:51 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 meme meme    8 Sep 22 13:51 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 meme meme   14 Sep 22 15:45 file 3
```

Using sed, 1 means line 1, d for delete, to remove the first line:

```
$ ls -lh | sed 1d
drwxr-xr-x 2 meme meme 4.0K Sep 22 14:33 dir1
-rw-r--r-- 1 meme meme    8 Sep 22 13:51 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 meme meme    8 Sep 22 13:51 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 meme meme   14 Sep 22 15:45 file 3
```

The `paste` program, and process subsitution `<(...)` is the key to combining these otherwise separate outputs. Paste normally expects files as arguments, eg `paste data1 data2`. We use bash's process substitution so the output of commands will appear to paste as ordinary files it can work with, thus:

```
$ paste <( ls -lh | sed 1d ) <( custom_command * )
drwxr-xr-x 2 meme meme 4.0K Sep 22 14:33 dir1   YYYdir1ZZZ
-rw-r--r-- 1 meme meme    8 Sep 22 13:51 file1  YYYfile1ZZZ
-rw-r--r-- 1 meme meme    8 Sep 22 13:51 file2  YYYfile2ZZZ
-rw-r--r-- 1 meme meme   14 Sep 22 15:45 file 3 YYYfile 3ZZZ
```

The use of bashrc merely saves this command for convenient re-use in new terminals, or existing terminals where you run `. ~/.bashrc` to reload bash.

Comment: I like this approach, unfortunately `ls1` looses the ability to have file arguments but only works with all files (`custom_command *`).

Comment: As a super noob, I'm using this with `stat -c "%a %n"` to show me octal permissions  when I `ls -la`.